# Lambda layer is not attached while deploying from jenkins

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-lambda

I am facing issue, while deploy from local machine using sls deploy, the lambda layer is successfully attached with lambda function but when try to deploy with jenkin, my lambda function is successfully deployed but not attaching lambda layer. Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you share your pipeline?

Comment: got the issue. Its my serverless version that cause. serverless 1.36 version have support of lambda layer but I had lower version on my jenkin.